# I get an error while selecting a random url for selenium though the number is in the list in python .How can i fix it

Tags: python, selenium, automation

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import random

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
videos = [
    'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HPLJ-k8Mt-I'
    'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nN1XDURBNYo'
    'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KUTXpFO2yDo'
    'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MccLaedI05g'
    'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eHMSMGfkGjY'
    'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c86GdHQaLsY'
    'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dz59GsdvUF8'
    'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xjv1sY630Uc'
]

for i in range(1000):
    print("vid is running for", i,)
    randomvideo = random.randint(0, 3)
    print(randomvideo)
    driver.get(videos[randomvideo])
    sleep_time = random.randint(5, 10)
    time.sleep(sleep_time)

driver.quit()
```

output is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/asus/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/selenum practice.py", line 21, in <module>
    driver.get(videos[randomvideo])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

how to fix this!!!!
The value is from one of the list
SORRY!!this is the first time using stackoverflow
Please help

Comment: you need to write commas to separate list items ['hello', 'its me']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be written like this

```
videos = [
    'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HPLJ-k8Mt-I',
    'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nN1XDURBNYo',
    'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KUTXpFO2yDo',
    'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MccLaedI05g',
    'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eHMSMGfkGjY',
    'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c86GdHQaLsY',
    'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dz59GsdvUF8',
    'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xjv1sY630Uc'
]
```

Comment: This should nail the OP